# Is it possible to train a custom LLM *on* a Google Colab Notebook?

Tags: python, openai-api, large-language-model

To clarify, I don't want to *run* the LLM inside a Notebook, I want to *train* it on a Google Colab Notebook.

Is there a way that you can train an LLM to answer questions based on the code inside in a Colab notebook? So essentially, it will be a chatbot capable of explaining the code, or parts of the code to the user, who is not so skilled in coding.

Would it be possible using Langchain's `NotebookLoader`? Or would I have to have another LLM translate the entire code to text and then pass that text to my main LLM??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR;
You can use LangChain `LanguageParser` and specify your codebase language such as python.You can read more about this function [here](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/document_loaders/source_code) and you can follow the [RAG over code](https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/code_understanding) guide to make your own QA model.

Using LLM to answer questions from codebase is quite common using Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG). The trick lies in splitting the codebase efficiently so that LLM
understands the context better. Splitting on top-level functions and classes and keeping their description separate has been in practice while building a QA model.

RAG approach requires you to store embeddings of your documents created by an embedding model such as OpenAIEmbeddings into a [vector database](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores) (like chroma, epsilla or pinecone). A retrieval strategy like MMR (Maximum marginal relevance) to get a relevant but diverse set of documents (that potentially hold the answer) is then deployed. Using this set, we produce a final answer, either by
stuffing all the documents retrieved into LLM or chaining LLM replies to fine-tune its response.

You might find [this course](https://www.deeplearning.ai/short-courses/langchain-chat-with-your-data/) taught by Harrison Chase about RAG to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easily. You probably want to use retrieval-augmentation rather than finetuning though, unless you have a dataset of thousands of Colabs.

With a sufficiently large context window (or a sufficiently small file) you can even do the whole thing in-context.

Comment: How would you do retrieval-augmentation? Using vector databases? And do you store python code inside the vector embeddings, or a description of that code?